# Count Characters in Perl

Tags: perl, for-loop, character

I need to count the letter "e" in the string 
`$x="012ei ke ek ek ";`

So far, I've tried with a for-loop:

```
$l=length($x);

$a=0;
for($i=0;$i<$l;$i++)
{$s=substr($x,$i,1);
if($s=="e")
{$a++;}

print $a;
```

Comment: Please lay out your code properly. It is unreadable and won't even compile.

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`!

Answer (score 7):

Your code has  some problems. You forgot to close  the `for` loop brace,
and in Perl `==` is supposed to compare numbers. Use `eq` for strings.

It is  also recommended that  you use  warnings and enable  strict mode,
which would  have helped  you debugging  this. In  your case,  since `e`
would be  treated as 0,  so the other one  char substrings, `1`  and `2`
would be the only characters not equal to `e` when compared with `==`. A
cleaned up version of your code could be written as:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $x = "012ei ke ek ek ";
my $l = length $x;

my $count = 0;

for(my $i = 0; $i < $l; $i++) {
    my $s = substr($x, $i, 1);
    $count++ if ($s eq "e");
}

print $count;
```

There are multiple  ways to achieve this.  You could use a  match with a
group,  which if  global returns  all the  occurrences in  list context.
Since you want  the number, take this result in  scalar context. You can
achieve this for example with:

```
my $count = () = $string =~ /(e)/g;
```

Or:

```
my $count = @{[ $string =~ /(e)/g ]}
```

Another way is  to split the string into characters  and grep those that
are *e*:

```
my $count = grep $_ eq 'e', split //, $string;
```

And probably the most compact is to  use `tr` which returns the count of
characters in scalar context, although  this does restrict this usage to
counting characters only:

```
my $count = $string =~ tr/e//;
```

Answer (score 0):

You compare characters with the numeric operator (`==`) when you should use the string comparison `eq`.  If you had used the `warnings` pragma you would have seen that.

You code should have looked like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $x = "012ei ke ek ek ";
my $l = length($x);
my $a = 0;
for ( my $i = 0; $i < $l; $i++ ) {
    my $s = substr( $x, $i, 1 );
    if ( $s eq "e" ) {
        $a++;
    }
}
print "$a\n";
```

Proper indentation and the use of the `strict` and `warnings` pragmas will avoid and/or catch unintentional, dumb errors.

A much more Perl-ish (and shorter) way to achieve your answer is:

```
perl -le '$x="012ei ke ek ek";@count=$x=~m/e/g;print scalar @count'
4
```

This matches globally and collects all the matches in list context.  The scalar value of the list gives the number of occurrences you seek.

Another way is to use [tr](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)

```
perl -le '$x="012ei ke ek ek";print scalar $x=~tr/e//'
4
```

Comment: Not me, but its surely because you didn't really help the OP. Please point out what they did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`@sidyll` Already mentioned what is the problem in your script and all  of the possible ways, but TIMTOWTDI.

```
$x="012ei ke ek ek ";  
my $count; 
$count++ while($x=~/e/g);  
print $count;
```